# Moving the 3d object in iOS application?

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es

I am working on rotating the 3d object in my application by using the application downloaded from [here](http://github.com/antonholmquist/rend-ios.).I succeed on stopping the rotating object as below, but I can't rotate the object again from the stopped position.Below is the piece of code I've worked from the downloaded project

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    if (aRotate) {
        [self startOrStopAutorotation:nil];
    }
    if ([[event touchesForView:self.view] count] > 1) // Pinch gesture, possibly two-finger movement
{
//CGPoint directionOfPanning = CGPointZero;
}
    else{
        CGPoint currentMovementPosition = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:glView_];
        [self renderByRotatingAroundX:(lastMovementPosition.x - currentMovementPosition.x) rotatingAroundY: (lastMovementPosition.y - currentMovementPosition.y) scaling:1.0f translationInX:0.0f translationInY:0.0f];
        lastMovementPosition = currentMovementPosition;
    }

}

}
- (void)renderByRotatingAroundX:(float)xRotation rotatingAroundY:(float)yRotation scaling:(float)scaleF translationInX:(float)xTranslation translationInY:(float)yTranslation{
    
    glView_ = [[REGLView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320) colorFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 multisampling:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:glView_];
    
    
    camera_ = [[RECamera alloc] initWithProjection:kRECameraProjectionOrthographic];
    camera_.position = CC3VectorMake(0, 0, 320);
    camera_.upDirection = CC3VectorMake(0, 1, 0);
    camera_.lookDirection = CC3VectorMake(0, 0, -1);
    camera_.frustumNear = 10;
    camera_.frustumFar = 640;
    camera_.frustumLeft = -glView_.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    camera_.frustumRight = glView_.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    camera_.frustumBottom = -glView_.frame.size.height / 2.0;
    camera_.frustumTop = glView_.frame.size.height / 2.0;
    
    scene_ = [[REScene alloc] init];
    scene_.camera = camera_;
    
    world_ = [[REWorld alloc] init];
    [scene_ addChild:world_];
    
    director_ = [[REDirector alloc] init];
    director_.view = glView_;
    director_.scene = scene_;
    
//    currentCalculatedMatrix = CATransform3DIdentity;
    GLfloat currentModelViewMatrix[16]  = {0.402560,0.094840,0.910469,0.000000, 0.913984,-0.096835,-0.394028,0.000000, 0.050796,0.990772,-0.125664,0.000000, 0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000};
    currentCalculatedMatrix = CATransform3DScale(currentCalculatedMatrix, 0.5, 0.5 * (320.0/480.0), 0.5);
    
////    if ((xRotation != 0.0) || (yRotation != 0.0))
//{
GLfloat totalRotation = sqrt(xRotation*xRotation + yRotation*yRotation);

CATransform3D temporaryMatrix = CATransform3DRotate(currentCalculatedMatrix, totalRotation * M_PI / 180.0,
((xRotation/totalRotation) * currentCalculatedMatrix.m12 + (yRotation/totalRotation) * currentCalculatedMatrix.m11),
((xRotation/totalRotation) * currentCalculatedMatrix.m22 + (yRotation/totalRotation) * currentCalculatedMatrix.m21),
((xRotation/totalRotation) * currentCalculatedMatrix.m32 + (yRotation/totalRotation) * currentCalculatedMatrix.m31));
if ((temporaryMatrix.m11 >= -100.0) && (temporaryMatrix.m11 <= 100.0))
currentCalculatedMatrix = temporaryMatrix;

    float currentScaleFactor = sqrt(pow(currentCalculatedMatrix.m11, 2.0f) + pow(currentCalculatedMatrix.m12, 2.0f) + pow(currentCalculatedMatrix.m13, 2.0f));

xTranslation = xTranslation / (currentScaleFactor * currentScaleFactor);
yTranslation = yTranslation / (currentScaleFactor * currentScaleFactor);
// Use the (0,4,8) components to figure the eye's X axis in the model coordinate system, translate along that
temporaryMatrix = CATransform3DTranslate(currentCalculatedMatrix, xTranslation * currentCalculatedMatrix.m11, xTranslation * currentCalculatedMatrix.m21, xTranslation * currentCalculatedMatrix.m31);
// Use the (1,5,9) components to figure the eye's Y axis in the model coordinate system, translate along that
temporaryMatrix = CATransform3DTranslate(temporaryMatrix, yTranslation * currentCalculatedMatrix.m12, yTranslation * currentCalculatedMatrix.m22, yTranslation * currentCalculatedMatrix.m32);

if ((temporaryMatrix.m11 >= -100.0) && (temporaryMatrix.m11 <= 100.0))
currentCalculatedMatrix = temporaryMatrix;
[self convert3DTransform:&currentCalculatedMatrix toMatrix:currentModelViewMatrix];    
   

// Black background, with depth buffer enabled
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

And below is the code I've worked for stopping and stopping

```
- (void)startOrStopAutorotation:(id)sender;
{
    id dLink=nil;
    if (aRotate){
        dLink=[[REDisplayLink sharedDisplayLink] observers];
        [[REDisplayLink sharedDisplayLink] removeObserver:[dLink objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    else{
        CADisplayLink *aDisplayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleAutorotationTimer)];
[aDisplayLink setFrameInterval:2];
[aDisplayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        //          [[REDisplayLink sharedDisplayLink] addObserver:[[REDirector alloc]init]];
    }
    aRotate = !aRotate;
}
```

Comment: Once "aRotate" becomes FALSE or NO, doesn't that mean your method "startOrStopAutorotation" never execute again?

Comment: aRotate returns false..but i touches the object renderByRotatingAroundX: method called....its not working ...

Comment: Vignesh, not sure if you're open to alternatives but there's this native graphics engine written iOS: http://nineveh.gl/. Not sure what you're trying to achieve with rotating a 3D object in your app. This code isn't pure OpenGL ES nor does it look like an easy to use engine. NinevehGL engine had a more easier way if all you want to do is rotate a 3D object.